# Get JSON response from wordPress website, woocommerce with basic authentication

Tags: android, json, wordpress, woocommerce, android-volley

I am developing an android application that get products of a wordPress site.
Woocommerce plugin is installed on website.
I can get Json of that site with Postman software using basic authentication. username and password are api key and api secret that wordpress website generated.
there is no problem when I use GET methed with Postman. butI have problem when I want to connect to website via android app, and got Error.
here is how i request Json data:

```
 public void newMyResponse(String url){

    //RequestQueue requestQueue;
    queue.add(new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            url,null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            Log.d("Products",response.toString());

            for(int i=0; i<response.length(); i++){
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject_products = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    Log.d("Items id: ",jsonObject_products.getString("id"));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d("Error8", error.getMessage());
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {

            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            String credentials = "ck_...:cs_...";
            String auth = "Basic "
              +Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(),Base64.NO_WRAP);
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            headers.put("Authorization", auth);
            return headers;

        }
});
```

Comment: Can you post your error

Comment: It just says: "D/Volley: [1] 8.onErrorResponse: Error8"
that "Error8" is the string I loged
@A.Gun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after some days of searching, finally i found out the problem.
My website uses https with self-sign certificate. So the application needs certificate to work with it. 
First of all, download your site certificate as mentioned  here:
[Export Certificate](https://www.wikihow.com/Export-Certificate-Public-Key-from-Chrome)
So as I found out, the best way is to add below code to the oncreate method of the activity that is going to authenticate:

```
hurlStack = new HurlStack() {
        @Override
        protected HttpURLConnection createConnection(java.net.URL url)
                throws IOException {
            HttpsURLConnection httpsURLConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) super
                    .createConnection(url);
            try {


httpsURLConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(getSSLSocketFactory(getApplicationContext()));

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return httpsURLConnection;
            }
        };
    queue = newRequestQueue(this, hurlStack);
```

I should mention that queue and hurlStack should define as:

```
 private RequestQueue queue;
 private HurlStack hurlStack;
```

Then, add the certificate of your website to raw folder, in my case, file name is certificate.and add these method to the activity you are working on:

```
 public SSLSocketFactory getSSLSocketFactory(Context context)
        throws CertificateException, KeyStoreException, IOException,
        NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {

// the certificate file will be stored in \app\src\main\res\raw folder path
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        InputStream caInput = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.certificate);

    Certificate ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
    caInput.close();

    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");

    keyStore.load(null, null);
    keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

    String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
    tmf.init(keyStore);

    TrustManager[] wrappedTrustManagers = getWrappedTrustManagers(tmf.getTrustManagers());

    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sslContext.init(null, wrappedTrustManagers, null);

    return sslContext.getSocketFactory();
}

private TrustManager[] getWrappedTrustManagers(TrustManager[] trustManagers) {

    final X509TrustManager originalTrustManager = (X509TrustManager) trustManagers[0];

    return new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return originalTrustManager.getAcceptedIssuers();
        }

        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            try {
                if (certs != null && certs.length > 0) {
                    certs[0].checkValidity();
                } else {
                    originalTrustManager
                            .checkClientTrusted(certs, authType);
                }
            } catch (CertificateException e) {
                Log.w("checkClientTrusted", e.toString());
            }
        }

        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            try {
                if (certs != null && certs.length > 0) {
                    certs[0].checkValidity();
                } else {
                    originalTrustManager
                            .checkServerTrusted(certs, authType);
                }
            } catch (CertificateException e) {
                Log.w("checkServerTrusted", e.toString());
            }
        }
    }};
}
```